# Powershell for Linux: Combining commands with pipe sign doesn't work

Tags: linux, powershell, ubuntu, powershell-core, psscriptanalyzer

Any way to concatenate commands in Powershell for Linux?

This is what I'm trying to run:

`pwsh -Command Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path . | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath "/home/administrator/scripts/test.json"`

So, run the Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer, convert the results to Json and save the result to test.json.

It doesn't recognize anything after the | sign:

`./test.sh: line 1: ConvertTo-Json: command not found`

`./test.sh: line 1: Out-File: command not found`

I need this to go in a bash script, hence the need to launch pwsh with the -Command option.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your `|` symbols are interpreted *by your Linux shell* (such as `bash`), *not* by PowerShell.

There are two soutions:

- Preferably, quote the entire `-Command` argument (a `'...'` string in a POSIX-compatible shell such as `bash` uses the string's content *verbatim*):

```sh
pwsh -Command 'Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path . | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath "/home/administrator/scripts/test.json"'
```

- Alternatively, individually `\`-escape all Linux-shell metacharacters that you want to *pass through* verbatim, such as `\|` and `\"` in this case:

```sh
pwsh -Command Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -Path . \| ConvertTo-Json \| Out-File -FilePath \"/home/administrator/scripts/test.json\"
```

<sup>Note: In this case, `pwsh` receives *multiple* arguments after `-Command`. However, PowerShell simply *joins them* before interpreting the result as PowerShell code.

This differs from the command-line processing of POSIX-compatible shells, which interpret the *first* post-`-c` argument as an implicit, ad-hoc *script*, with  *additional* arguments getting passed as verbatim arguments *to that script*, accessible as usual as `$1`, ...</sup>